# What is the Chap of the Manor?

Tags: family-guy

In Family Guy S10E22 "Family Guy Viewer Mail #2", Brian says that Family Guy is based on an English show named "Chap of the Manor".

Ιs there actually a show that resembles that?

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_Guy_Viewer_Mail_2#.22Chap_of_the_Manor.22%2a%2a) doesn't have any insight.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Family Guy is just having a laugh and spoofing the brits. (And as for the *why*, who knows? The show is pretty random.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That Wiki link actually has a lot of insight.  The first line in the plot section:

> The episode uses the premise that Family Guy is based on a British
>   television show.

**Premise** being the key word.

In the Cultural References section:

> In the interlude to the Chap of the Manor segment, Stewie jokingly
>   says that Family Guy is based on The Simpsons, another animated comedy
>   series, but later claims it is based on a British television show,
>   like the TV series The Office.

The reference to The Simpsons should give you an indication that the tongue is firmly planted in cheek.

> The Chap of the Manor segment featured references to the classic
>   British series Benny Hill (manic, sped up chase sequence between
>   Peter, Chris and the coppers), sketch show Monty Python's Flying
>   Circus (jump cut to footage of old dowagers clapping & laughing in the
>   cutaway gag), and Fawlty Towers (letter R falling off of the word
>   "Manor" in the title sequence).

Too many obvious references to other famous British shows.

Putting all of this information together, it's pretty obvious that Chap Of The Manor is fictional.